# Insert decimal values into MySQL with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, double, decimal, mariadb

I'm working on the following problem and I can't find a answer.

I have got the following Code:

```
    public void CreateCmd (string g_cmd,params object[] g_params)
    {
        int i = 0;
        MySqlCommand cmd = verbindung.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = g_cmd;
        foreach(object param in g_params)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?param"+i.ToString(), param.ToString());
            i++;
        }
        verbindung.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

The method is working fine (so far) but if I want to insert a double to the MDB it got shortened by the database (?). E. g.:

The code I call the method with:

```
database.CreateCmd("INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `time`, `tax`, `netto`, `brutto`) VALUES(NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?param0, ?param1, ?param2)", 0.19, 201.5, 239.785);
```

The input wich is shown in PHPMyAdmin:
[Screenshot from PHPMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAQ22.png)

The structure of the table (I've tried different data types):
[another cs of MDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIeqc.png)

I hope you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Greetings 
Polarety

Comment: Maybe it is too early and my wheels haven't started fully spinning yet, but what is it you mean when you say "MDB"? _It makes me think you are talking about MSAccess._

Comment: Im using XAMPP with MariaDB (MDB) instead of MySQL. I know its nearly simular but I don't know if this is the reason why it didn't work.

Comment: AddWithValue cannot know in advance what is the datatype on the database and so it builds a string parameter because of your ToString()but this converts your input in a string using your locale settings. The database doesn't like a comma as decimal separator and wants a point.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I tried to add an .replace(",",".") befor but it didn't work. Idk why now it works! Thank you! PS: I'm new on StackOverflow but I suggest I should write the Answer for the european guys, right?

Comment: The answer was provided earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a culture issue, where the database is expecting a comma (,) instead of a period (.)?

Otherwise, check if the database is setup to be `UNSIGNED`, per the documentation [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/decimal/) for MariaDb

Also, since you are storing money, please be aware of floating-point issues. Maybe you should consider a fixed-point instead?

Answer (score 0):

Right.

After I edited

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?param"+i.ToString(), param.ToString());
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?param"+i.ToString(), param.ToString().Replace(",","."));
```

It works. Thank you!